# When does jQuery .append() act like .insertBefore() last child vs. as documented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

http://jsfiddle.net/foaje732/2/
HTML source:

```
<p id="words">Words
    <p>
        <label>Q1
            <input type="text" id="q1" name="myinput" />
        </label>
    </p>
</p>
```

Jscript:

```
$('#words').append($('<p></p>').html("This is clearly in the wrong place."));
```

What you actually get:

```
Words.
This is clearly in the wrong place.
Q1 [input field]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your mark up is wrong, the `p` element cannot contain another block element, it can contain only inline elements. So the actual html rendered by your markup in the browser will be as below, which makes your output correct.

```
<p id="words">Words</p>
<p>
    <label>Q1
        <input type="text" id="q1" name="myinput">
    </label>
</p>
<p></p>
```

So one possible solution you can look for is to use `div` as the external container like

```js
$('#words').append($('<p></p>').html("This is clearly in the wrong place."));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="words">Words
  <div>
    <label>Q1
      <input type="text" id="q1" name="myinput" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Arun is absolutely correct. if Jason will do the same thing inside div means each <p> replace by <div> then Jason will got correct structure as @Jason want

Answer (score 0):

We cannot get any child `<element>` inside `p` element, the `$('#words').children()` will return 0 so that it `append` your code at the top of `p` ( after words -text, not any element).
In this case if you want to fix it, try change `p` to `div`:

```
<div id="words">
    <p>Words</p>
    <p>
        <label>Q1
            <input type="text" id="q1" name="myinput" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#words').append($('<p></p>').html("This is clearly in the wrong place."));
})
```